# How to find concavity for sine with second derivative $f''(x)= -2(2\sin x-1)(\sin x+1) $?

Tags: calculus

The second derivative is $f''(x)= -2(2\sin x-1)(\sin x+1) $

I found the values of zero at: $$\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{5\pi}{6} \text{ and} \frac{3\pi}{2} $$

Concave down at $(\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{5\pi}{6})$
concave up at $(\frac{5\pi}{6}, \frac{3\pi}{2} )$ and $(\frac{3\pi}{2} , 2\pi)$

How do I find its concavity between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{6}$?

I am really struggling with this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f''(x)= -2(2\sin x-1)(\sin x+1) $. Take any $x$ value between $0,\pi/6$, and substitute this into $f''(x)$. The sign of the result tells you the concavity.

For example, consider $x=\pi/12$. $\sin\pi/12=0$, so $f''(x)=-2(-1)(1)=2$, which is positive.